# While loop is running even though one of the conditions by the and is false

Tags: python

```
spam = 1
lam = ""

while spam < 5 and lam != 2:
    print("What is 1 + 1")
    lam = input()
    spam = spam + 1
    
if spam < 5:
    print("You got it right")
    
else:
        print("You got it wrong")
```

After I put 2 as my input lam = 2 making the condition false. However it still runs 4 more times due to the spam instead of ending.

Comment: you probably want `lam` to be an `int`eger:  `lam = int(input())`. otherwise: `lam != "2"`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to typecast `lam` to int since you are comparing it to `2`.
Try in this way:

```
spam = 1
lam = 0

while spam < 5 and lam != 2:
    print("What is 1 + 1")
    lam = int(input())
    spam = spam + 1
    
if spam < 5:
    print("You got it right")
    
else:
    print("You got it wrong")
```

Answer (score 2):

**if you dont want to typecase just compare it with `'2'` instead of int 2**

```
spam = 1
lam = ""

while spam < 5 and lam != '2':
    print("What is 1 + 1")
    lam = input()
    spam = spam + 1
    
if spam < 5:
    print("You got it right")
    
else:
        print("You got it wrong")
```